# host localhost is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I've accidentally deleted my users table (removed all users) now whenever I try to access my database it says: "host localhost is not allowed to connect to this MYSQL Server". I've tried connecting directly, same error. I'm using apache xampp for this.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

A very commonly asked question, try doing this (and it worked for me), 
goto your **mysql** folder and there will be a file called `my.ini`. Simply add `skip-grant-tables` (without an argument) in the `[mysqld]` section as below:

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
skip-grant-tables
```

Save the file, restart your server.
If the problem still exists, refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087492/host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server-1130).

Comment: One more detail. Firewall on server computer might cause some issues with access to mysql. Just good to remember.

Comment: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
[mysqld]