# how can i fix this Error in Wamp_Server?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

**I have problem in my wamp server . I dont know how to fix that . You can see the Error in photo ??**
[image]

*help me . Thanks*

Comment: Did you care to Google the message? It has to do with your MySQL server not setup correctly. Example result from Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003590/host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

Comment: Did you install MySQL on your machine?

Comment: have you checked the connection Parameter ....

Comment: @K.I Evidently he did, as MySQL responds.

Comment: no body can answer to the question ??

Comment: Some explanation for downvotes: The question demonstrates impatience, no research effort whatsoever, & doesn't even transcribe the error message into text where it can be more readily indexed so others can find it later.  It's also probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087492/host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server-1130) and/or off-topic as a better fit for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) if it were a better quality question. SO likes to punish people who try to answer such low quality questions (as you can see below).

Comment: Can you edit your question to paste in the lines of PHP code where you create the MySQL connection object and any before that where you set variables that are used, EXCEPT `$password` (and if you're not using a variable for that, replace it with one for your post). Examples might look like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username and password PHP is using to try to connect to MySQL is not recognized as a valid set of credentials by the MySQL server.  Check to make sure you have the credentials entered correctly in PHP and that the user exists in the MySQL database, allowed to access from LOCALHOST.
Do answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087492/host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server-1130) help?

Comment: Why is this answer being downvoted?

Comment: i dont know . my question has downvote too

Comment: @bzeaman Certain members of the Stack Overflow community like to punish folks who try to be helpful to people who ask low quality questions, and the OP hasn't read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There maybe many reasons for the downvote. First if there is a question with same Problem, you should mark the question as duplicate and not link to it in your own answer. Second one, because the question can be solved by googling.

Comment: I hadn't found the likely dupe at first because answering directly was actually easier.  That the question demonstrates low research effort is an issue that in my opinion should lead to downvotes on the *question* rather than its *answers,* but others clearly disagree.

Comment: @Jens Also, I don't have the dupehammer, though I did flag it.