# Host 'XXX' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server (V.8)

Tags: mysql

When trying to connect to MySQL running on a local network I'm getting the error message:

```
Host 'XXX' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.
```

## Disclaimer (MySQL Ver 8)

The answers provided bellow do not solve te problem in MySQL **v8**

[Host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server)

[host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server (#1130)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087492/host-localhost-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server-1130)

The solution provided in these old answers are returning the following error in MySQL Ver 8.0.13.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass123' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Or

```
Grant All Privileges ON *.* to 'root'@'%' Identified By 'pass123';
```

Output message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'pass123' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line
>   1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

The GRANT syntax has changed in V8, you no longer need or are allowed the `IDENTIFIED ..` part.

```
CREATE USER 'fred'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT All ON db.* to 'fred'@'%';
```

Or for anywhere on your local lan segment maybe something like this

```
GRANT All ON db.* to 'fred'@'10.0.0';
```

Comment: Indeed MySQL below version 8 allowed to automatic creating a user within the GRANT statement with `IDENTIFIED BY ...`

Comment: `GRANT All ON db.* to 'fred'@'%'; ` should be `GRANT All ON db.* to 'fred'@'localhost'; ` is this example by the way..

Comment: Yea @RaymondNijland Was not sure if the OP wanted access from anywhere or just locally. As they say a server running on their network I assumed it was not going to be `localhost`

Comment: `localhost` will do for a LAN environment. Now it gives me: `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'`. The root user is already there. I just need to grant the permissions.

Comment: `root` is automatically granted permissions to do anything. NOTE: You should not use `root` for normal access by for example a we site! Create an account specific to the app and grant it ONLY the rights and privilages it requires for normal useage